# External Hard Drive Drop/Fall

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I actually am having a problem for which I would really appreciate some advice.

Yesterday night my external 500GB (USB) hard drive (a big one, with case) fell. It was on my PC and fell down on the carpet. It was in its case of course but the cable was moved a bit and it fell on the carpet. I was using the HD at that time. I was watching a movie that was located on the Hard Drive. After the fall my computer does not recognize it.

When I plug it in I can hear the sound of the HD (which I guess means it gets power) but it does not appear as an external HD. I used "Disks" in Ubuntu to see if the system can detect the HD and it appears in that application as a USB HD. I tried then to right click on the HD and "Create a Disk Image" but I had no luck at all. I am sure that the HD can power on (because of the sound) and it is recognizable from Ubuntu's Disks Application and Windows Disk Manager as well. My problem is that it's not accessible. I have more than a lot of data stored on this Hard Drive.

Any ideas to save it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from the case and use normal connectors to try to access the drive: it might be just a data channel cable that was broken during the fall.

If you remove the drive from the case you will find yourself 99.9% of the cases with a perfectly normal hard disk that can be plugged in to a computer and accessed as a normal drive. If plugging it in to the computer as a normal drive gives you the same results (disk is visible but seems that there is no access to it) then I would start to be worried about your data.

If plugging it in to the computer works then I would say its just a matter of buying a extra hard disk USB case and installing the drive back.

Comment: I tried plugging the hd on my pc. Still, I can hear the sound it makes but I cannot find anywhere :(

Comment: do you hear any click sounds? If you do then probably the heads are damaged or touching the plates, there is a solution for that (get a similar model drive and replace the plates from the old to the new drive).

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/454253/how-to-restore-information-from-dead-hdd

Comment: Dear Bruno, to be honest, I am afraid to do such a thing on my hard drive. It contains my latest backup and I really wouldn't like to risk it... There are some Data Recovery Companies that offer a free HD Diagnosis. I will get informed about the HDs' damage and let you know for more details...